Twilio call cost for non US (US1) calls ? (for example IE1 calls)
I am trying to get the cost of calls on Twilio thanks to the Call SID.
Here is my code:
account_sid = 'my_sid'
auth_token = 'my_us1_token' or 'my_ie1_token'
call_sid = 'a_call_sid_from_us1_region' or 'a_call_sid_from_ie1_region'

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
call = client.calls(call_sid).fetch()
print(f"Price: {call.price} {call.price_unit}")

Everything works fine when I put 'my_us1_token' and 'a_call_sid_from_us1_region' together. I get something like this:
Price: -0.01000 USD
If I use 'my_ie1_token' with 'a_call_sid_from_ie1_region' I get the following error on code line: 'call = client.calls(call_sid).fetch()'
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twilio/rest/api/v2010/account/call/__init__.py", line 392, in fetch
    payload = self._version.fetch(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twilio/base/version.py", line 141, in fetch
    return self._parse_fetch(method, uri, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twilio/base/version.py", line 112, in _parse_fetch
    raise self.exception(method, uri, response, "Unable to fetch record")
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: 
HTTP Error Your request was:

GET /Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Calls/CAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json

Twilio returned the following information:

Unable to fetch record: The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxx4/Calls/CAxxxxxxxxxxx.json was not found

More information may be available here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404

Any idea how to solve this issue ? Seems to be a bug on Twilio side :( but just to be sure...
Thanks.

I'd suggest to fix the formatting with markdown. This way, you can increase your chance of getting more valuable answers. The error message suggests that the call sid is not accessible from that account. Can you confirm that you are using the right credentials for the right account?

Formatting corrected. I confirm that my credentials are correct.

ANSWER TO MY QUESTION :
The non-US region has to be specified in the client:
client = Client(
  settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
  settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN,
  region='ie1',
  edge='dublin'
)

See: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python#specify-region-andor-edge
Note that all APIs are not available in non-US regions. https://www.twilio.com/docs/global-infrastructure/regional-product-and-feature-availability
Hope this will help!
